# Code OnTime ASP.Net code generator

Tags: asp.net, code-generation

Does somebody tested Code OnTime on a real world project (codeontime.com)? Technology looks promising, but their free version restrictions are too restrictive. I managed to put only few tables in a model, real DB has 20+tables. Also it is not clear how generated site works where DB contains lot of records. To my surprise I didn't find any reviews or blog posts on this topic. I consider to buy a license, but I'm in doubts.

If not Code OnTime, are there any other decent code generator? All I need is front end to DB and simple security.

Thank you,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Holy buzzwords batman.  That site looks a little scary to me.  I can't speak to the code it generates, but if you're looking for a decent front-end to a few database tables, [ASP.NET Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata) comes to mind.  For some reason, it's not one of the more well-known features of ASP.NET, but it really should be.  There are a lot of tutorials out there on the web, and it will probably do everything you're wanting it to do.

Comment: Unfortunately Dynamic Data is not an option. It was my first attempt. Like any new Microsoft technology, it looks attractive only on demo video. When you are trying to make one step in other direction, it fails completely. You end up customizing

Comment: every single page, and do all coding, no scaffolding support there. So it is good idea and nice try, but this technology is not production ready, it is geek joy.

Comment: I doubt you spent much time with it, then.  Too bad.

Comment: Perhaps yes. I spent enough to estimate coding time. If you need custom template for each and every table, what support can you get from DD? What the point in making separate template for every table? There is no other way for customization.

Answer (score 0):

This tool is database structure based, to get the must you need an efficient database design. To apply complex business rules you need to program either on `SQL or C#`. The code that CodeOntime generates is simple and with a good architecture. I have tested browsing a couple of hundred thousand records table and it does a very good job. It really saves time with the upfront programing but in my perception you need to be a good programmer to get the most of CodeOnTime.

Answer (score 0):

I have used CodeOnTime on a number of different projects now and the performance seems very good when accessing data.  I agree with what MRM has said - your database design is paramount to generating good CodeOnTime output.  Then, depending on your needs, you can add your own custom business logic on top of the generated code using either C# or VB.NET.  Also, it integrates well with ASP.NET Membership and generates the related admin/security pages related to maintaining users and roles for your app.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend my code generator http://code.google.com/p/magicapps/ , is an open source project and can generate code for asp.net and winform from any kind of data-database. Another feature I like from my project is that can create snippets and not only projects, so you can create snippets for your needs. And the best, is free.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I couldn't resist adding my two cents about CodeOnTime.  When were looking at it we found at least three issues that ruled it out from my perspective:

- The way it wants to log all of your design changes in a local XML log file so it can "replay" them in the future is hostile to collaborative development using source control.  We got frequent conflicts on this log file between just two developers, so we actually split the tasks and assigned the CoT development to one person to avoid conflicts.  The last I heard, they were looking at writing some sort of server tool to manage the merging of multiple simultaneous developer changes.  To me, this sounds doomed to fail.
- It has a "Url Hashing" mechanism to prevent people from tampering with Urls by encrypting with a private key.  However, it also exposes the Url encoding function to the client.  So, if I want to tamper with a Url, I just create an arbitrary Url, and call the encoding function myself to get the encoded version.  I (or an unsuspecting victim) can then request the encoded Url, the server will decode it as though it were one it generated, and then my arbitrary Url is used.  What's worse, is that the private key has a default value and the user is not required to change it!
- After monitoring some of the AJAX traffic sent between client and server, I found it was trivial to create a POST request to get data back from the server, including the generated website's user catalog - with no authentication necessary!  I reported this to them in November 2012 and I've just tested that the flaw still exists in their "Northwind in the Cloud - Windows Azure Demo" site.

If you're thinking of using CodeOnTime, I'd only do so if you were planning a single developer and a handful of users on an internal network.  Anything bigger than that then I'd wait for them to take security seriously.